# Angular 2 - Template recursive not working

Tags: treeview, angular2-template

I'm trying to do a treeview in my component.html this is my code :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of menusList">
    <div class="containerMenu">
        <span [ngClass]="{collapseTitle:item.SubItems.length}">
            <i [ngClass]="item.SubItems.length ? 'fa fa-angle-down' : ''"></i>
            <span style="display:inline-block">
               <span>{{item.Title.Traductions.French}}</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <div *ngIf="item.SubItems.length" ng-include="'menu'" class="collapsePanel"></div>
    </div>
</div>

    <!--Submenu Template + Récursive-->
    <ng-template #menu>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of item.SubItems">
                <span ng-if="!item.Url" ng-class="{collapseTitle:item.SubItems.length}">
                    <i ng-class="item.SubItems.length ? 'fa fa-angle-down' : ''"></i>
                    <span ng-class="item.SubItems.length ? 'subItemsTitle' : ''">
                        <span style="display:inline-block">
                            <span>{{item.Title.Traductions.French}}</span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>

                <a target="_blank" href="{{item.Url}}" ng-if="item.Url">
                    <span ng-class="item.SubItems.length ? 'collapseTitle' : ''">
                        <i ng-class="item.SubItems.length ? 'fa fa-angle-down' : ''"></i>
                        <span ng-class="item.SubItems.length ? 'subItemsTitle' : ''">
                            <span style="display:inline-block">
                                <span>{{item.Title.Traductions.French}}</span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </a>

                <div *ngIf="item.SubItems.length" ng-include="'menu.html'" class="collapsePanel"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ng-template>
```

So, my first div cross all my array(menusList) and if the current position have subitems, it should include the template#menu. This is working in AngularJS, but I want to do it in Angular2.

I have no error in my console, and I think my problem is the `ng-include`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2753#issuecomment-117937921) in issue #2753, ng-include is not supported in Angular 2+.

You can, however, wrap your ng-template into another component, with SubItems as input. That way you can recursively call the same component, achieving the desired result.